# Recovering local git changes made in vs code after signing onto github in vscode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Recently I have signed into my github account in VScode due to which all the local git changes I made are lost. Is it possible to get the code back. I noticed that .git file is not present for some reason on using ls -a command in the folder

p.s. I haven't deleted any .git folder. But now it's showing an error there is no .git folder at all

Comment: signing out should not affect your code. Deleting (even for mistake) the .git folder on the contrary does. Please, describe what you did exactly, and try to reproduce it on a dummy repository.

Comment: @Daemon Painter I haven't deleted the .git folder. VScode simply prompted that I could sign in to my github account in vscode so I did and the next moment all the .git files were deleted

Comment: @DaemonPainter No

Comment: Check if you can recover the .git folder from the trash bin.

Comment: "the .git folder is gone" is indeed bad news. Are you positive you ran `ls -a` in the correct directory ? To see if your `.git` folder could be in a parent folder : run `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`.  To see if the `.git` folder could be in a child folder : run `find . -name '.git'`

Comment: Does moving the folder from Desktop to the another folder delete the .git in that folder?

Comment: No, moving the folder should have brought your `.git` folder along. What *could* have happened though is : if your project folder was  `$HOME/Desktop/some/project`, but for some reason the `.git` directory was in a parent directory (`$HOME/Desktop/some`, `$HOME/Desktop` or `$HOME`), then it would have stayed there.

Comment: What is your OS ?

Comment: Windows 10 Home

Answer (score 1):

Check your stash to see if your changes didn't end there :

```
# will list modified files in your latest stash :
git stash show
# will show you the complete diff of what was stashed :
git stash show -p
```

If you don't see your changes there, check the older stashes :

```
git stash list

# you can view any older stash :
git stash show stash@{2}
git stash show -p stash@{2}
```

Comment: Won't help much: the .git folder is gone.